# Omnet++ : Ad Hoc Network

Tags: adhoc, omnet++

I am new to Omnet++. Although I have tried some basic examples such as Tic-Toc and Source-Sink, I cannot figure out how to implement more sophisticated networks.

Problem : I want to implement Ad Hoc Network. I have tried examples given in INET but they only ping each other and reply. They do not exchange actual messages. I want my network to have actual information in form of messages and then communicate these messages through ad hoc network to different nodes. Please help!!

Comment: anyone with answer to my problem??

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with the examples in inet/examples/adhoc/ieee80211 and inet/examples/manetrouting.

As for 'real' traffic. You are free to configure any traffic type you wish in the hosts. Pinging is just an example. Take a look at inet/examples/inet/udpburst to see how burting UDP traffic is configured.

Traffic generated by the applications inside a hosts are totally independent of how they are communicating (just as in real life). I can ping and run a browser equally with both a wireless and a wired connection.

i.e. you CAN combine the different examples.