# Creating Ad-Hoc network in Omnet++

Tags: routes, omnet++, adhoc

As I said in the title, I have to create Ad-Hoc network with running routing protocols. The problem is that I never use Omnet++ and I don't know how to do it. If anyone could help me by giving useful tips would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Omnet++ : Ad Hoc Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985113/omnet-ad-hoc-network)

Answer (score 0):

I used Ad-Hoc network model of OMNET++ for my bachelor's thesis. At the beginning, it seems a little bit hard to use. Anyway, I think this tutorial will help you to understand key points. I'm enclosing link of the tutorial page:
      https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/tutorials/wireless/index.html